# Export Active Directory Users as *.contact

Tags: active-directory, export, contacts

Is there a way to export AD Users to a *.contact file? (each contact = 1 file)

Answer (score 3):

On Powershell to import all users and their contact details to CSV:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title, Department,OfficePhone,MobilePhone | Select Name,Title, EmailAddress, OfficePhone, MobilePhone, Department  | Export-Csv contacts.csv
```

To have separate files (depends on which format you want):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory     
$allusers = Get-ADUser -filter * | Select SamAccountName

    foreach ($user in $allusers) {

        $user = $user.SamAccountName
        $contact = Get-ADUser $user -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title, Department,OfficePhone,MobilePhone | Select Name,Title, EmailAddress, OfficePhone, MobilePhone, Department

        echo $contact > $contact.Name

    }
```

That will put the contact details each to a separate file in the following format:

```
Name         : John Doe
Title        : Engineer
EmailAddress : jdoe@email.com
OfficePhone  : 1234 1234
MobilePhone  : 1234 1234
Department   : Sample Department
```

Format as you like using echo if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can export users with Powershell to a CSV then import using Windows Address Book.